# Why the std::bind for a callback method doesn't match the declared one thus it compiles?

Tags: c++, c++11, bind

I've created a minimal example to illustrate my question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

class Bar {
public:
    void bind_function(std::function<void(int)> callback){
        m_callbacks.push_back(callback);
    }

    void invoke() {    
        for(auto& c : m_callbacks){
            c(12345);
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::function<void(int)>> m_callbacks;
};

class Foo{
public:
    void register_foo(){ m_msg.bind_function(std::bind(&Foo::callback_foo, this));  }
    void callback_foo(/*int a*/){ std::cout << "callback foo invoked!!!!" << std::endl;  }
    void run() { m_msg.invoke(); }
private:
    Bar m_msg;
};


int main(){
    Foo foo;
    foo.register_foo();
    foo.run();
    return 0;
}
```

I have a `Bar` class where it has two methods: `Bar::bind_function` to pass a function pointer to be pushed into some vector. And a `Bar::invoke` method which will invoke the callbacks from the vector.

Then I have a `Foo` which has three methods: A `Foo::register_foo` method where I will invoke the `Bar::bind_function` from Bar and the actual method to be invoked `Foo::callback_foo`.
Finally a method to `Foo::run` the registered functions.

The code compiles and I can see the callback/registered method being executed.

**[QUESTION]**

Why does the code compile if the function pointer from this vector:

```
std::vector<std::function<void(int)>> m_callbacks
```

Doesn't match the actual callback:

```
void callback_foo(/*int a*/){...}
```

One is `void(int)` and the other is `void()`.

If I uncomment my `void callback_foo(/*int a*/){...}` to match `void callback_foo(int a){...}`

I get the following error:

```
 error: static assertion failed: Wrong number of arguments for pointer-to-member
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. The code you posted does not compile, but one has to add the includes. Then for the error its better to show the code rather than to desribe how the code has to be modified

Comment: Added the missing includes.

Comment: "Bar::bind_function to pass a function pointer ". `std::function` is **not** a function pointer. `std:function` is far more flexible. You're seeing part of this flexibility here; it can discard unneeded arguments. `std::function` can also store the results from `std::bind`, unlike function pointers.

Comment: BTW, you may want to read up on lambda's. Replacing the `std::bind` with `[this](int a){ callback_foo(a);}` is more readable IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> error: static assertion failed: Wrong number of arguments for pointer-to-member

The problem here is in `std::bind`. Since you added `int a` as an parameter, `Foo::callback(int)` now requires two arguments, and you only provided a `Foo*`. You need to tell `std::bind` what to do with the `int a` parameter.

In this case, you need to tell `std::bind` to **not** bind it. Instead, it should return a unitary functor (one unbound argument remaining). You do that by passing `std::placeholders::_1` :

```
std::bind(&Foo::callback_foo, this, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Comment: @Hasturkun question is tagged C++11

Comment: @Caleth: Oh, my bad. I didn't notice the tag and didn't see anything in the question body. I'll delete my previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

> Why does the code compile

Because you're using the **function adaptor** `std::bind` that generates a new callable object provided another callable object and some optional placeholder argument(s) as input(s).

This means that the expression `std::bind(&Foo::callback_foo, this))` generates a new callable object that **takes arbitrary number of argument** and calls `&Foo::callback_foo` with the passed `this` pointer and ignoring the remaining argument(s).

The important thing to note here is that the newly generated callable ignores the remaining arguments.

---

Next, that newly generated function object is stored in `std::function` which gets invoked when you wrote `c(12345)` which in turn invokes `Foo::callback_foo` with the stored `this` pointer while the argument `12345` is ignored.